# I want to remove the backslashes that are introduced in the xml output in aws lambda. My code is in python

Tags: python, xml, aws-lambda, namespaces, backslash

The xml string in my python console output is free of backslashes. but when I run the code as a lambda function in aws lambda, the output contains backslashes before every double-quote (`"`).

I have tried replace and other methods, but I think that this problem arises at the last level. The output of aws lambda is reproduced on my console when I do json.dumps on the dictionary that contains the xml string as the body and some Id in the place of application Id

The output of the function in my python console looks like this:

```
amount="-900.0" category="Others" balance="1068.78"
```

The output in the aws lambda is :

```
" amount=\\"-900.0\\" category=\\"Others\\" balance=\\"1068.78\\"
```

How do I ensure that my lambda output is in the same format?

Comment: ... the `\\"` are escaped backslashes (\\) that escape an inline `"` ... because this would make no sense: `" someone said "Florida is a warm place" while others shoutet "There is no beer in Hawai" ` - you would not know where the string starts/ends

Comment: @PatrickArtner How do I fix that?

Comment: I found one method. You can do this by altering the output mapping template of API and lambda.